# SQL Server : concatenate a variable into a bulk

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to concatenate a variable within a bulk

```
DECLARE @XmlTable TABLE (XMLDATA xml)  
DECLARE @TEST varchar(100)

SET @TEST = 'F-44-44-5840-9F2B-5DA852'

INSERT INTO @XmlTable (XMLDATA)
    SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\torresf\Desktop\Contabilidad\Xmlmariela\'+ @TEST+'.xml' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS X;

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.sat.COM' as cfdi)
-- INSERT INTO @XmlTable2 (Total)
SELECT
    Serie = cfdi.value('@Serie','nvarchar(20)'),
    Folio = cfdi.value('@Folio','nvarchar(50)'),
    [Version] = cfdi.value('@Version','nvarchar(4)'),
    Fecha = cfdi.value('@Fecha','varchar(10)'),
    Rfc = cfdi2.value('@Rfc','varchar(50)'),
    SubTotal = cfdi.value('@SubTotal','decimal(18,2)'),
    TotalImpuestosTrasladados = cfdi3.value('@TotalImpuestosTrasladados','decimal(18,2)'),
    Total = cfdi.value('@Total', 'decimal(18,2)'),
    XMLDATA
    --UUID =cfdi5.value('@UUID','varchar(50)')
FROM
    @XmlTable
CROSS APPLY 
    XMLDATA.nodes('/cfdi:Comprobante')  AS MY_XML(cfdi)
CROSS APPLY 
    cfdi.nodes('cfdi:Emisor') as MY_XML2(cfdi2)
CROSS APPLY 
    cfdi.nodes('cfdi:Impuestos') as MY_XML3(cfdi3)
```

This is the error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'

Help, please.

Comment: Why all CAPS? It is bad manners ....

Comment: you can't use expression on `OPENROWSET`. For you requirement, you will need to use `Dynamic SQL` to form the `OPENROWSET` query and execute it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @XmlTable TABLE (XMLDATA xml)  
DECLARE @TEST varchar(100)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @Filepath varchar(100)

set @Filepath = 'C:\Users\torresf\Desktop\Contabilidad\Xmlmariela\'+ @TEST+'.xml'

SET @TEST='F-44-44-5840-9F2B-5DA852'

SET @sql = N'INSERT INTO @XmlTable (XMLDATA)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn 
 FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+ @Filepath + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS X;';

 EXEC sp_executesql @sql ;

 ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.sat.COM' as cfdi)
-- INSERT INTO @XmlTable2 (Total)
 SELECT
 Serie = cfdi.value('@Serie','nvarchar(20)'),
 Folio = cfdi.value('@Folio','nvarchar(50)'),
 [Version]=cfdi.value('@Version','nvarchar(4)'),
 Fecha = cfdi.value('@Fecha','varchar(10)'),
 Rfc = cfdi2.value('@Rfc','varchar(50)'),
 SubTotal = cfdi.value('@SubTotal','decimal(18,2)'),
 TotalImpuestosTrasladados =cfdi3.value('@TotalImpuestosTrasladados','decimal(18,2)'),
 Total = cfdi.value('@Total', 'decimal(18,2)'),
 XMLDATA
 --UUID =cfdi5.value('@UUID','varchar(50)')
 FROM
 @XmlTable
  CROSS APPLY XMLDATA.nodes('/cfdi:Comprobante')  AS MY_XML(cfdi)
  CROSS APPLY cfdi.nodes('cfdi:Emisor') as MY_XML2(cfdi2)
  CROSS APPLY cfdi.nodes('cfdi:Impuestos') as MY_XML3(cfdi3)
```